# In terms of accessibility, which button to use on the form?

Tags: html

Both `<button type="submit">` and `<input type="submit">` buttons can be used to send form data to the server. Both will have the same functionality, but which one is better to use for accessibility? Since the `<button type="submit">` element has its meaning in its own name, now the `<input type="submit">` element is not so clear its meaning, as the inputs are very relative.

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility tools do not read raw HTML to the user. Either kind of submit button will be presented in the same way.